# Update from PHP 5.3 to 5.4 on CentOS 6.3 while keeping Plesk

Tags: centos6, php5

I need to update the servers PHP version, but when I try to remove the old php to install the new PHP 5.4 via `yum` it wants to remove the whole plesk suite which I want to keep.

I followed this guide https://serverfault.com/a/461418/155005 but it didn't changed anything.

Is there a way to keep plesk and update php?

**Update:**
If I want to install the php 5.4 and then remove php 5.3, there is a conflict shown between the two `php-common` packages.

Comment: It is also possible to install multiple php-versions. You can also install PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.5 and select the version in Plesk. https://der-linux-admin.de/2014/12/centos-zusaetzliche-php-versionen-php-5-5-php-5-4-fuer-plesk-bereitstellen/

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't remove the old packages before installing the new packages. There's no need to do so.

Comment: Well, if I want to install php 5.4 there is a conflict between the two `php-common` packages

Comment: Did you run `yum update`?

Comment: When I run `yum update` it prints `No Packages marked for Update`

Comment: If that's the case, then you _did not_ follow the guide given in the post you linked to. Please edit your question and specify exactly what you did.

Answer (score 1):

You can`t update PHP from 5.3 to 5.4 using yum because Plesk panel does not allow it.
You can run Plesk installer and select update to version 5.4 if it available in Plesk installer menu.

[You can also install multiple custom configured PHP versions in Plesk 12 Oding](http://www.shkodenko.com/install-and-configure-custom-php-fastcgi-version-with-plesk-12/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did this:

```
rpm -e --nodeps psa-php5-configurator
yum remove php-common
yum install php54w php54w-common php54w-devel php54w-fpm php54w-gd php54w-pdo php54w-pgsql php54w-pecl-memcache php54w-mcrypt php54w-mbstring php54w-xml -y
```

Maybe this will help someone

Comment: Don't use `--nodeps` or similar unless you know exactly what you are doing. It almost guarantees an inconsistent system.