# pecl can't find PHP - 'No such file or directory'

Tags: php, centos6, pecl

I have updated PHP on a CentOS install to PHP 5.5 via the Remi repository. The `php-pear` package is installed.

However, when I try and run `pecl`, it can't find the PHP install;

```
[root@box etc]# pecl
/usr/local/bin/pecl: line 28: /usr/local/bin/php: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/pecl: line 28: exec: /usr/local/bin/php: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way I can reconfigure pecl and supply a PHP location?

Both `php -v` and an Apache-served `phpinfo()` return 'PHP 5.5.0', so PHP is definitely installed.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your php isn't installed in /usr/local/bin ?

Comment: Did you install pecl from source? Because by default the binary is located in /usr/bin/pecl

Comment: Bang on, @ALex_hha! Would you like to rephrase that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks @NickW, your question made me think harder about the problem.

Comment: Show the output of the following command "# rpm -qf /usr/local/bin/pecl"

Comment: @ALex_hha; 'file /usr/local/bin/pecl is not owned by any package'
Your comment reminded me that I installed PHP from src the other night and updated a symlink... Oops, forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest to remove all packages installed from source and install necessary packages via yum from http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/testing/CentOS/6/x86_64/

```
# rpm --import http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/IUS-COMMUNITY-GPG-KEY
# rpm -ivh http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-11.ius.centos6.noarch.rpm
# yum search php55 --enablerepo=ius-testing
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.colocall.net
 * epel: ftp.colocall.net
 * extras: ftp.colocall.net
 * ius: ius.cu.be
 * ius-testing: ius.cu.be
 * updates: ftp.colocall.net
ius-testing                                                                                      | 2.2 kB     00:00
ius-testing/primary_db                                                                           |  56 kB     00:00
================================================== N/S Matched: php55 ==================================================
php55u-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package php55u
php55u.x86_64 : PHP scripting language for creating dynamic web sites
php55u-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath library
php55u-cli.x86_64 : Command-line interface for PHP
php55u-common.x86_64 : Common files for PHP
php55u-dba.x86_64 : A database abstraction layer module for PHP applications
php55u-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
php55u-embedded.x86_64 : PHP library for embedding in applications
php55u-enchant.x86_64 : Human Language and Character Encoding Support
php55u-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php55u-gd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the gd graphics library
php55u-gmp.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the GNU MP library
php55u-imap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use IMAP
php55u-interbase.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use Interbase/Firebird databases
php55u-intl.x86_64 : Internationalization extension for PHP applications
php55u-ldap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use LDAP
php55u-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
php55u-mcrypt.x86_64 : Standard PHP module provides mcrypt library support
php55u-mssql.x86_64 : MSSQL database module for PHP
php55u-mysqlnd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php55u-odbc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use ODBC databases
php55u-opcache.x86_64 : The Zend OPcache
php55u-pdo.x86_64 : A database access abstraction module for PHP applications
php55u-pear.noarch : PHP Extension and Application Repository framework
php55u-pgsql.x86_64 : A PostgreSQL database module for PHP
php55u-process.x86_64 : Modules for PHP script using system process interfaces
php55u-pspell.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using pspell interfaces
php55u-recode.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the recode library
php55u-snmp.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that query SNMP-managed devices
php55u-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
php55u-tidy.x86_64 : Standard PHP module provides tidy library support
php55u-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML
php55u-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC protocol
```

Testing repo is disabled by default

Comment: Thanks @ALex_hha, you reminded me that 3 nights ago I had compiled PHP from src and had setup the symlink for pecl to point there... I fixed that symlink and was good to go!

I used the remi repository as detailed here:
http://serverfault.com/questions/456968/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-latest-php-version-in-centos-with-yum