# Upgrading PHP on RedHat

Tags: php, redhat, rpm

I'm trying to upgrade my PHP from 5.3.13 to 5.5 following [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/456968/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-latest-php-version-in-centos-with-yum/461418#461418), which links http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-apache-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/. However, I got error messages at the very first step that adds repositories:

```
$ sudo rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-4.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
epel-release >= 4 is needed by remi-release-4-7.el4.remi.noarch
$ sudo rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/4/i386/epel-release-4-10.noarch.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
fedora-release conflicts with epel-release-4-10.noarch
```

I'm using Red Hat 4.6.1:

```
$ cat /proc/version 
Linux version 2.6.40.6-0.fc15.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-12.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc      version 4.6.1 20110908 (Red Hat 4.6.1-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Oct 4 00:39:50 UTC 2011
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Fedora release 15 (Lovelock)
```

Current PHP:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.13 (cli) (built: May  9 2012 14:38:35)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: cat /etc/redhat-release ?

Comment: @ALex_hha Fedora release 15 (Lovelock)

Comment: First update Fedora to a supported version. Remember that Fedora has a very short 13-month lifecycle, so you must upgrade at least annually.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix Fedora release with Epel release. So I think the right way is to build php from src.rpm.

```
# rpm -ivh http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/testing/Redhat/6/SRPMS/php55u-5.5.3-1.ius.el6.src.rpm

# rpmbuild -ba --target=x86_64 php55u.spec
...
...
...
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/SRPMS/php55u-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.src.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-cli-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-fpm-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-common-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-devel-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-opcache-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-imap-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-ldap-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-pdo-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-mysqlnd-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-pgsql-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-process-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-odbc-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-soap-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-interbase-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-snmp-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-xml-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-xmlrpc-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-mbstring-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-gd-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-bcmath-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-gmp-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-dba-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-litespeed-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-mcrypt-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-tidy-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-mssql-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-embedded-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-pspell-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-recode-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-intl-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/php55u-enchant-5.5.3-1.ius.fc15.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One problem I'm worrying about is I have a php website that uses fastcgi. If I update php in this way, will my websites still work?