# Upgrading PHP on Fedora

Tags: php, fedora

I have a Fedora server running PHP 5.3.13 and Wordpress. I would like to upgrade the PHP version to 5.3.18 or higher.

This is the system information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux xxx.com 2.6.40.6-0.fc15.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Oct 4 00:39:50 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 15 (Lovelock)

$ php --version
PHP 5.3.13 (cli) (built: May  9 2012 14:38:35) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with eAccelerator v0.9.6.1, Copyright (c) 2004-2010 eAccelerator, by eAccelerator
```

I tried using `yum install update php`, but it doesn't work:

```
$ sudo yum update php
password for user:
fedora/metalink                                          | 5.6 kB     00:00     
updates/metalink                                         | 5.2 kB     00:00     
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

Any solutions? Please also let me know if upgrading PHP version will invalidate any previous installed softwares (e.g., Wordpress, php-cgi, etc). Thank you.

Comment: Why do you wish to so upgrade PHP?

Comment: @MadHatter The system admin tells me to fix security holes by upgrading the PHP version.

Comment: You asked this question six months ago, at http://serverfault.com/questions/541019/upgrading-php-on-redhat, though I note you have just (four minutes ago) deleted it.  The answer remains the same: you're running an old and unsupported version of Fedora.  If you bring your Fedora into support, you will automatically have security updates again, which will mean you're secure even if the version number suggests otherwise.  If you don't upgrade the OS, no number of PHP upgrades can keep you secure.

Comment: @MadHatter Are there any other ways to upgrade PHP?

Comment: Let me be incredibly clear: **noone else is using Fedora 15 any more**.  It is past end of life, and out of support.  You cannot secure an F15 installation at this point in time.  You can compile PHP from source if you want, but it will be painful, time-consuming, you will need to keep doing it each time a new PHP comes out, and **it still won't secure your system**.  If your sysadmin thinks it will, (s)he's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fedora 15 is not supported anymore, so php will not be updated. Upgrade to the latest version (fedora 20 at this time).

Fedora releases have short life cycles, so you should not use it for a server unless you can afford to upgrade your system at least every year.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like php was not installed through rpm, you should try to uninstall it and reinstall it via `yum install php`

Comment: Why should I uninstall it? I guess if I run `yum install php`, it will upgrade to the newest version if it's not.

Comment: you'd end up with two (probably at different locations), so uninstalling it would make it less confusing going forward)

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU What I provide, is an actual end solution and _NO_ critiques! Thank you for your comment though.